# Core Data Fetch Based on Entity Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to call from Core Data, everything that is associated with a specific category. The app is like this:

- Click a category
- Click a sub-category question
- view the question

I have the views all set up, and had a partner set up Core Data, but am running into the issue that regardless of which category I pick, it still always loads all questions.

I pass the category selection from the category list view, but I'm not sure what to do with it, and how I should be calling from Core Data. I have this currently (again, it returns all questions): `NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];`

The categories and questions have an inverse relationship in the data model. Should I be using predicates, NSRelationshipDescription, or something else?

Comment: What does your data model look like?  Are there a separate managed objects for Category, Subcategory and Question?

Comment: @bbarnhart Yeah, separate objects, with a relationship between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just access the `NSSet` of questions?  i.e. `category.questions`

To answer your question about the predicate:

If you are looking to find all `Questions` for a specific `Category` you will need to specify that `Category` in your `NSPredicate`

Something like:

```
(NSArray *)findQuestionsForCategory:(Category *)category {
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question" inManagedObjectContext:[appDelegate managedObjectContext]];
[fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"question.category == %@", category]];

... execute fetch request, handle possible errors ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSPredicate` (assuming you're using the traditional Master-Detail `UITableView` pattern and Storyboards):

```
// In CategoryViewController
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"categorySelect"])
    {
        Category *category;
        category = [categories objectAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        [segue.destinationViewController setParentCategory:category];
    }
}

// In QuestionViewController with @property parentCategory
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Question" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Create predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(category == %@)", self.ParentCategory];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    questions = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
}
```